# removing opacity to submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added opacity to the parent menu in jquery.I want to add opacity to parent menu but not sub menu.I have tried to remove opacity for '.dropdown-content'.but no luck.Even I have tried rgba for background instead of hex color code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.dropdown').css('opacity','0.5');
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4CAF51;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have provided an answer as per my idea using `: before` pseudo-element please check if it's woking for you.

Answer (score 2):

Add opacity with css `dropbtn` button instead `dropdown` menu

**OLD one**

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4CAF51;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

Added with `:before` pseudo  element

```css
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown:before {
content:"";
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
left:0px;
top:0px;
opacity:0.5;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4CAF51;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason I want to add opacity to dropdown

Comment: @user3386779 is it ok we use `: after` or `: before` for add opacity to dropdown.?

Comment: can u provide css using :after/:before

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/onn0cdk7/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.dropbtn').css('opacity','0.5');
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4CAF51;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for some reason I want to add opacity to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
i have modified your code , and i hope this is the thing you need 
you are applying opacity for entire div. so that is the reason you are 
getting 
the issue, so just remove javascript code and add the below code in css 

<!--------------- css --------------->
<style>
.dropdown .dropbtn
 {
   opacity: 0.5 !important;
 }
</style>
<!---------------------------------->

or replace the dropdown to dropbtn in your javascript

  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.dropbtn').css('opacity','0.5');
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's a workaround using `: after` on `.dropdown`

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown:after {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    content:'';
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    z-index:9;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4CAF51;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    opacity:1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```